# How convert text to pixel array in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new user of QT. Is it possible to convert for example one character or string to array where 0 means white field and 1 means black field? For example when I have character "a" saved as QString or any representation of font and I would like to get following array:

```
int array[9][6] = {                //"a" char array
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},         //- - - - - -
      {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},         //- * * * * -
      {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},         //* - - - - *
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},         //- - - - - *
      {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},         //- * * * * *
      {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},         //* - - - - *
      {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1},         //* - - - * *
      {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1},         //- * * * - *
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},         //- - - - - -
};
```

Is there any way in QT for reach that goal ? I hope I describe my problem as clear as possible and someone can help me with this?

And very important thing size array must depend on selected font size, so if I choose for example 30 pt font, array should be appropriate bigger than 10 pt font.

Thank You very much.
Best regards.

Comment: What do you mean by a pixel array?

Comment: I dont know how to name it, but by "pixel array" I mean this array which is shown as example above in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misinterpreted the question on my first read through... well, here is what was asked for...

[image]

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QVector>
#include <QFontMetrics>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSize size;
//    QPixmap pixmap(100,100);
    QImage image(20,20, QImage::Format_Mono);// Change the width and height here as needed if your letters get too big
    image.fill(0);
    {
        QPainter painter(&image);
        //// alternative to fill method
        // painter.setBrush(Qt::black);
        // painter.drawRect(0,0,image.width(), image.height());
        painter.setPen(Qt::white);

        QFontMetrics fm(painter.font());
        size.setHeight(fm.height());
        size.setWidth(fm.width('a'));

        painter.drawText(0,fm.height(),"a");
    }
    QLabel label;
    label.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image).scaled(400,400, Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
    label.show();

    QVector <QVector <int> > array(size.height(), QVector < int> (size.width(), 0));

    for(int r = 0; r < size.height(); r++)
        for(int c = 0; c < size.width(); c++)
            array[r][c] = (image.pixelColor(c,r) == Qt::white ? 1 : 0);

//    qDebug() << size << array;
    foreach(QVector <int> row, array)
        qDebug() << row;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
QVector(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
QVector(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
QVector(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
QVector(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
QVector(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
QVector(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
QVector(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
QVector(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
QVector(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
QVector(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)
QVector(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
QVector(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
QVector(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thank You very much for Your reply. That's what I really need ! I learned a lot from Your code, thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

You can draw text onto a bitmap image, which will give you a bitmap containing text. Which is a pixel array, for all intents and purposes.

Note that you will also have to use a "bitmap font", regular fonts won't really do the trick as most have been created to utilize antialiasing and won't result in a crisp and readable bitmap image.

Qt also offers font metrics, which can give you a clear idea how big text or individual characters are.